What is the most healthy and cost-effective alternative to an air conditioner for the purpose of cooling?
I am looking for a practical solution to cool single rooms only, on very hot days. I stay away from air conditioners, because:

they always make me sick (I guess it's the find dust they spread
around); they require frequent cleaning and still pollute the air
nonetheless;
high initial cost;
expensive and burdensome maintenance;
noisy;
make the facade look ugly.

Any alternatives?

Swamp cooler, maybe?

The simplest method of personal cooling is a humble fan. Point it at you on a low setting and make sure you stay hydrated. The goal there is to get fresh air on your skin for your sweat to evaporate, you don't need much air movement for that.
Anything that actually cools is going to want to move the air around as well to avoid the cool air simply pooling below it. So that is not going to be solved by anything else. Also the dust they move around was already there, so a clean room will reduce the amount of dust thrown around. Adding some filters (aka air-purifiers) will also help with that.
If you actually want cooling then a portable model will help. Prefer the models with 2 hoses, inlet and outlet, those are more efficient.

I am old enough to remember the alternatives to air conditioning.

Evaporative coolers.  These work in low humidity environments.  Arizona, etc.  They evaporate water and cool the air by doing so.  You would probably be familiar with these if they worked where you live.
Attic fans.  This was the gold standard back in the day.  Usually in the hall, a huge fan that blows up into the attic, it pulls in outside air and gives the added benefit of cooling down the attic.  The show Home Improvement riffed on this in an episode.
Other fans.  Box fans for windows, blowing in or out depending on prevailing winds, ceiling fans, reciprocating fans.  Fans make you feel cooler.
Shade.  Trees to the south (Northern hemisphere) and west keep the sun of the house.  Awnings over windows keep the sun from shining through windows.  Thick curtains keep the sun out as well.  Cheap students used to use aluminum foil in the windows to keep their power bills low (and hide their grow rooms).
Manage heat.  Don't do much during the hot part of the day.  Don't cook or run large appliances.  Get your house cool in the morning if where you live actually gets cold at night (this doesn't work in south Louisiana).
Oddball other solutions.  You can blow air underground to cool it and then blow it into your space.  Build your house in a hill to lower your heat load.


Depending on how long you care to wait, and what kind of trees and curtains you choose, managing sunlight can help quite a bit.  Our house has plenty of shade trees.  While they don't hang over the roof, they leave much of the sides of the house in shade most of the summer.  Also, we use light-blocking curtains to prevent the sunlight from baking us.  The east window curtains are drawn in the morning, the south in the afternoon, and the west towards evening. We run a simple fan or two to keep the air circulating, which doesn't really change the temperature but does "seem" cooler to the people.
The only time it doesn't work is when the heat comes with oppressive humidity.   Then we find ourselves pining for AC even despite the drawbacks you mention.
But for now, plant yourself some shade outside and block the sunlight.
